# BufferedReader not returning null at the last line

Tags: java

The last line contains nothing , yet it does not return `null`. Code is as follows

When debug using `Eclipse`, I saw `line= ""` in debug mode, how do I prevent this from happening

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   // process the line.
}
br.close();
```

Comment: Is there a line break at the end ot the last line in the file?

Comment: If you're using Java SE 7, consider to use the new Automatic Resource Management feature to manage your streams.

Comment: Please consider reading the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Answer (score 6):

You don't prevent it from happening, an empty line is a line, so it will be returned as is.

What you can do is to check if the line is empty before processing:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   if (!line.isEmpty()) {
       // process the line.
   }
}
br.close();
```

Comment: Was writing this exact same answer.  +1

Comment: Basicly a  correct answer, but suffers from the same issue as the original post. Use the new Automatic Resource Management feature to manage your streams or close them properly in a finally block.

Answer (score 4):

The BufferedReader.readLine() method returns null when it reaches the end of file.

Your program appears to be reading line in the file before it reaches to the end of the file. The condition for terminating  is that line is null, empty string is not null so it loop and  dont get terminated.

Comment: I think the OP realises that. Your answer needs to explain why `null` is not being returned (i.e. because there is an empty line at the end of the file).

Answer (score 2):

If the line consists of a single line break `line` will be empty `String`, but `readLine` will not return null. `readLine` only returns null once you reach the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

nulll = nothing. 
"" = empty.
If the last line is empty "" is expected. The following line should be null.

from there you can test for emptyness (I like the appache StringUtils isEmpty) or remove last \n from your file prior to processing.